# Why is the Java compiler giving the incoherent ".class expected" compile error?

Tags: java, if-statement

If I have a piece of code like this:

```
public class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (true)
            int a = 0;
    }
}
```

When I compile it, Java compiler produces an error

> .class expected.

- I know that when we don't use braces, we can use only one statement after `if`.
- And I also know that I will not be able to use the `int` variable `a`, because as soon as the `;` is encountered, the program comes out of `if`, and the variable `a` loses it's scope.

I am **not surprised** that this code emits an error, but **why** is the error message **'.class' expected**?

What is Java compiler trying to say?

[image: Screenshot of compiler error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the *only* token sequence that can legitimately follow the keyword token of `int` in this case is `.` followed by `class`. The declaration statement you've got at the moment isn't valid because a local variable declaration on its own isn't a Statement as per [JLS 14](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement). (It's a BlockStatement.)

Note that in the tutorialspoint environment referenced in the comment, if you use a class instead of `int`, a different error is produced - potentially because the set of valid tokens is different in that scenario. (`String.getClass();` would be valid for example, whereas `int.getClass();` wouldn't.)

There is a valid question asked in a comment:

> Why this `.class` thing? If you know any situation in which `int` followed by `.class` can compile, then please tell me.

And that's easy - you can call a method on the `Class` reference returned by `int.class`:

```
public class ABC
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if(true)
            int.class.getName();
    }
}
```

That's not *useful* code, but it is *valid* code. It compiles for me without warnings or errors.

As mentioned in comments, more recent compiler versions give more useful errors - I would recommend upgrading.

Comment: So you mean to say that the answer to my question is that __the only token sequence that can legitimately follow the keyword token of *int* is .class__?

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh: Yes, that's basically what the first sentence of the answer says. (Although `.class` isn't a single token, I believe - I'm not terribly hot on exact parsing details though.)

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to what [some commenters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462906/why-is-java-compiler-giving-an-incoherent-class-expected-error?noredirect=1#comment56667543_34462906) say, this code can actually produce that error.

```
int a = 0;
    ^
```

According to the Java Language Specification, a variable declaration needs to be in a **code block**:

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block. Local variable declaration statements may be intermixed freely with other kinds of statements in the block.

I assume you already knew that.

**But why the *.class expected* error?**
The reason why the exception says *.class expected*, is compiler specific. Other compilers will emit *not a statement* or *illegal start of expression*.

My guess is that it is related to the way the compiler evaluates the code. The only way `int` can be valid at that location, is when followed by `.class`. So as soon as the token `int` is detected, the compiler expects it to be followed by `.class`.

For example,

```
if (true)
    int.class.getFields();
```

would be a valid statement.

So the compiler gives an error that is in some way logical, that is, *.class expected*.
Other compilers probably evaluate the whole statement as a variable declaration, rather than separate tokens like `int`, `a`, `=` and `0`.

**Specific compiler**
I do not know which specific compiler tutorialspoint.com is using, but their javac version (using `javac -version`) is `javac 1.7.0_75` on `Fedora release 21 (Twenty One)` (using the command `cat /etc/issue.net`).

*PS: I don't know if you have a specific reason for using the compiler of which you posted an image, but I suggest you start using Eclipse or Netbeans.*

Comment: No-one has said it would compile without an error. (If you think someone has, please quote that...) Everyone has said it doesn't normally produce the error claimed by the OP, in a compilation normal environment.

Comment: So have you managed to reproduce that error on your machine, directly from the command line? If so, it would be useful if you'd quote the javac version number you're using...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, my bad. I said *an error*, but meant *that* error. Furthermore, I did not mean to say that I have managed to reproduce this code *on my own machine*, but the compiler tutorialspoint.com is using, actually *does* exist. What kind of compiler — I added as much as details I could find for now. I only hope this answer is not in vain. You're way quicker than me; I just needed more time.

Comment: The advantage of using a well-known IDE is that problems with the IDE are easier to solve, because many people are using it, increasing the chance that someone has the same problem. In addition, if you got used the BlueJ IDE, then switching to a more advanced IDE is more difficult.